# Вывод содержимого файла Java

Tags: java

Есть такие блоки кода:

```
@Override // Для вывода содержимого файла
public void Read() throws FileNotFoundException { 
    Scanner KFileScanner = new Scanner(Kfile);
    for (String Str : KFileScanner.next().split("/")) {
        System.out.println(Str);
    }
    KFileScanner.close();
}
@Override // Для записи в файл
public void Write() throws IOException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(Kfile, true));
    Scanner InputFile = new Scanner(System.in);
    String InputText = InputFile.nextLine();
    pw.println(InputText + "/");
    pw.close();
}
```

Я в конце каждой введенной строки добавляю `/` и пытаюсь вывести содержимое файла разделяя(имеется ввиду перенося на новую строку) этим слешом. Для лучшего понимания, покажу с скринами:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я хочу, вывести эти две строки как есть, с их переносом и пробелами, т.е. в консоли после вывода должно быть так:
`name lastName lastLastName`
`home lastHome lastLastHome`

А выводит как видите только первое слово `name` и завершается.
**Каким образом написать метод `Read()` чтобы он выводил содержимое файла перенося строку в нужном месте?**

*Остальной код [здесь](https://github.com/nosferatu-id/thekeeperTerm/blob/master/TheKeeperTerm/src/com/keep/Main.java), он небольшой только 56 строк*

Comment: Зачем вам слеш как разделитель если вы используете перевод строки? Читайте файл в цикле построчно и пишите в файл без слеша.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.next()` читает до первого пробела, т.е. только первое слово. Читайте сразу строками с помощью `.nextLine()`, тогда и слэш не понадобится (хотя он и так не нужен, как правильно в комментарии написали).

Или же вам нужно читать через `.next()` в цикле до тех пор, пока файл не закончится. Тогда можно и со слэшем, если так нужно.